# How to get a company-token for "Apply With Linkedin" js button

Tags: javascript, button, linkedin-api

I would like to embed the **"Apply With Linkedin" (with JS) feature - button** in a company's site.

I already created an **app** here ( https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps/MY_APP_ID_HERE )

And require to obtain the data-company-token to use it inside JS code

(Currently get the following **error**: "Error trying to initialize the widget! Error is:companyToken: error.invalid.company.token" since i have not the company id - company-token yet)

In dev docs here https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/lts/apply-with-linkedin
states that:

> data-company-token="{CompanyID value provided by LinkedIn}"

PS: I've tried to use the id from company's linkedin page url (getting it from url) but without luck

**What actions required to get one (company-token) ?
Need to become a partner ?**